# vb.net combine two or more events

Tags: vb.net

I have four `textbox` for an IP Address. Each `textbox` is for each of the octate.

When the control loses focus or when user presses `ENTER`, it will check if the value is greater than 255.

```
Private Sub txtParametersIpFirst_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtParametersIpFirst.KeyPress
    If e.KeyChar = Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(Keys.Return) Then
        'Check if Value is more than 255
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub txtParametersIpFirst_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtParametersIpFirst.LostFocus
    'Check if Value is more than 255
End Sub
```

Is there something that these two events be combined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to combine two events is by calling a method..

```
Private Sub Logic()
  'Check if Value is more than 255
End Sub

Private Sub txtParametersIpFirst_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtParametersIpFirst.KeyPress
    If e.KeyChar = Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(Keys.Return) Then

      Logic()

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub txtParametersIpFirst_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtParametersIpFirst.LostFocus

  Logic()

End Sub
```

However, if you're to combine two same events, for example two Lostfocus event of two different textboxes, then you can just add handles;

```
Private Sub txtText1_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtText1.LostFocus, txtText2.LostFocus, 

  ' Code similar for both textbox
  ' You can use the Sender param to verify who's triggering the event

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you go for masking like this ###.###.###.### and use the Validation event to confirm that the value entered is a valid IP address.By this way there is no need for four different text boxes

There is some good material on [This link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4693/IP-Address-TextBox).and [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a66c2b2b-3f40-4ffb-8e1e-b9020fbd96dc/reg-exp-for-check-input-textbox-ip-address-with-padded-leading-zeros?forum=regexp)